# mount.cifs error 14 but smbclient works

Tags: mount, cifs

I have a debian server and I want to mount an external Win2008R2 share using cifs. I get:

```
error 14: bad address.
```

Using the same arguments with `smbclient` I can connect with success and browse share content.

my command is:

```
$ mount -t cifs //server-ip/sharename /local/mount/dir/ -o user=username%password
```

Answer (score 2):

you also need to install  "winbind" in samba server
"apt-get install winbind" and try to mount in windows

Comment: mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.1.179,unc=\\192.168.1.179\wwwroot,,ver=1,user=mauro,pass=********
mount error(14): Bad address

Comment: I installed `samba-winbind` on my CentOS 7 smb server, and started the winbind service. Then my client could run mount.cifs correctly.